# After upgrading POS module, only incognito window catches the right appearance

Tags: magento-1.9, upgrade, admin-panel, third-party-module

I have upgraded Point of Sales module. If I enter admin panel in incognito window, the new table and buttons of POS are aligned well, otherwise they are misplaced and product images are not displaying in its list.
I emptied the cache but did not help.

Comment: clear the browser cache.

Comment: I was looking for another solution, since I always tell my client clear your browser cache and seems they don't like it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seams that your static files are cached.
You need to clear the browser cache.
If this is not an option because you cannot tell your clients to do so you can try [this free extension](https://github.com/jreinke/magento-suffix-static-files).
It allows you to add a version to your static files.
The only thing you have to after a deployment is go to the system->configuration section and change the version number of the static files.
This should solve your problem.